# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Push Notification through Proxy Server

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I would like to use a proxy server for push notification. In worklight.properties, how to specify username and password for APNS?

```
#   Push GCM proxy settings
#push.gcm.proxy.enabled=false
# protocol may be either http or https
#push.gcm.proxy.protocol=
#push.gcm.proxy.host=
# negative value means default port
#push.gcm.proxy.port=-1
#push.gcm.proxy.user=
#push.gcm.proxy.password=

#   Push APNS proxy settings
#push.apns.proxy.enabled=false
# only SOCKS proxy is supported at the moment
#push.apns.proxy.type=SOCKS
#push.apns.proxy.host=
#push.apns.proxy.port=
```

Comment: I assume you've tried push.apns.proxy.username/password?

Comment: Yes, tried. Seems in APNSMediator.java (com.worklight.integration.notification.apns), there is no such attribute be defined? I can only see push.apns.proxy.enabled, push.apns.proxy.type, push.apns.proxy.host and push.apns.proxy.port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've checked.

For Push Notifictions Worklight uses [notnoop](https://github.com/notnoop). The current version bundled in Worklight does not have username/password support in APNS proxy (which is of type SOCKS and I am not sure if it at all supports this method, either). It does not exist in the bundled version.

Note: it is not possible to upgrade notnoop in Worklight, it is integrated within.

Comment: Thanks Idan. Since username and password for GCM can be specified in Worklight. I assume that it is supported in GCM proxy?