# APNS push via proxy, mobilefirst v7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Running MobileFirst Server 7.0 on Linux

Trying to send Push Notifications. We are required to use a proxy server for outbound communications.

For GCM we specify proxy settings, which must include a username and password.

I'm not clear what is possible for APNS.

I see this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710603/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-1-push-notification-through-proxy-server) which seems to indicate that we cannot specify a username and password when using SOCKS, and SOCKS is the only supported proxy.

Are we saying that MobileFirst push to APNS cannot be used via a proxy requiring authentication? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOCKS is the only supported proxy for APNS push notifications. The ability to use a secured SOCKS proxy, by providing credentials in the JNDI properties, is being worked on (PI45521 UNABLE TO SEND PUSH NOTIFICATION VIA APNS IF THE MOBILEFIRST SERVER IS BEHIND AUTHENTICATION ENABLED SOCKS5 PROXY).

This will be available in a later interim fix build.
You can choose to open a PMR to be notified and receive the iFix when available.